# sql server transpose rows to column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Project | State
----------------
1       | A
2       | A
2       | F
3       | A
3       | F
3       | P
4       | S
5       | C
```

What i would like to to is get a table like this :

```
Project | State
----------------
1       | A
2       | AF
3       | AFP
4       | S
5       | C
```

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: This is not transpose, this is grouping of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT Project,
  (SELECT State + ''
   FROM table t
   WHERE t.project = m.project
   FOR XML PATH(''))
 FROM table m
 GROUP BY Project
```